# D7000 multiple exposure with mirror up?

Tags: nikon-d7000, multiple-exposure, mirror-lockup

I shoot a lot of close-up photography and typically use the mirror up feature with a remote control. I tried doing double exposures using these functions and kept failing. Yesterday I switched to single shot and the mutiple exposure function worked fine. I just wanted to make sure that I wans't making some mistake. In short, multiple exposure does NOT work with the mirror up, right?
Thanks!
Tim

Comment: _In continuous high-speed and continuous low-speed release modes, the camera records all exposures in a single burst._ Camera Manual - Page #153

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of pages 152-153 of [your manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/D7000_EN.pdf) is that you have to capture the correct number of frames (2 or 3 as chosen in the menu) in order for the "multiple exposure" sequence to be complete.

As @alen mentions in his comment above, burst modes will mean those 2-3 frames are captured relatively quickly, but in other shooting modes, you still have to go through all the steps of acquiring a complete frame **for each** frame that makes up the multiple exposure.

For single shot, that simply means taking two pictures. The same applies in mirror lock-up mode BUT MLU requires **two** button presses to acquire **one** frame (see pg 83 of your manual for MLU details), so the process must be repeated for each subsequent frame required to complete the Multiple Exposure sequence. And it *is* a sequence, it is initiated and can be cancelled via the shooting menu. See pg 154 for "Interrupting Multiple Exposures".

Comment: As the acronym goes _RTFM_ :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, I'm making two complete exposures after selecting "2" in the menu. I made an error in my earlier post; I wrote "mirror up" (which is what happens), but I achieve that using the remote function--click to raise the mirror and click to make the expose. But remote release and continuous release are not available together, so far as I can tell from the dial.

Comment: @tim please update your post to reflect the actual question then, as it is very unclear what the issue is. Since we have actually answered your question as it is phrased, and that information could be useful to someone, you might even be better off asking a different question altogether.