# How do I combine mirror lockup and bracketing on my Nikon D7500?

Tags: nikon, bracketing, mirror-lockup, nikon-d7500

[This](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22375/2321) question asked about multiple exposures with the mirror up on a D7000.  I have a slightly different question.

Is it possible to combine mirror lockup with bracketing on a D7500?

I haven't seen anything in the manual that says no (but I may have missed it), and when I just tried what I thought was the correct setup I only got a single image.  I think this is because the dial on the camera means you select between C<sub>L</sub>, C<sub>H</sub>, or M<sub>Up</sub>, with the C modes related to slow and fast continuous shooting.

[Here](https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/d7500/en/11_release_mode_03.html) is a link to the D7500 manual (for mirror lockup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use live view mode. The mirror is locked up in live view mode.

Comment: Just FYI. Earlier Nikons, and lower model Nikons, cycle the mirror for still photography; even in live view mode (because the mechanism for stopping down the aperture is linked to the mirror).

Comment: Specifically: in terms of digital models, the D3xx0 and D5xx0 models, as well as the previous entry level models they replaced like the D40 & D60, are the ones limited by the same motor powering the mirror and aperture lever via the same movement. Most film Nikons (maybe all or almost all?) are the same. The D7xx0 models can change the aperture without cycling the mirror.